# how to use doctrine schema update without symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Hello i am trying to use doctrine in an PHP application (not symfony) 
and this is my app structure :

```
- public
- app
- vendor
   -doctrine
   ....
```

How to execute doctrine commands in this case ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [DoctrineConsole](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#doctrine-console) that is not related anyhow to symfony

[Here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/tools.html#command-overview) you can find all the commands

In particular

> `orm:schema-tool:update` Processes the schema and either update the database schema of EntityManager Storage Connection or generate the SQL output.